# Trouble with rigging, automatic weights not working

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, rigify

I'm having trouble with my character. It's made of several seperate objects and when it comes to rigging The automatic weights don't work, I get the error message that a weight solution couldn't be found for one or more bones. some parts move correctly, some bones move parts of the mesh they're not connected to, and some just don't move at all. Also Pose mode really really lags, not sure if that's related
[image: mesh not moving as it should][image: .]

I've removed doubles and loose verts, recalculated normals, I've also tried rigging the individual parts seperatly by selecting the bones that will effect that part of the mesh in pose mode and parenting But I'm yet to figure this out. My topology isn't great, I'm not sure if that could be the reason

I'm still a noob, any help would be greatly apreciated.

I'm using Blender 2.80

Comment: I'm not very experienced with rigging/animation myself, but my understanding is that failure of automatic weighting isn't necessarily your fault. It's just that complicated models are difficult for Blender to solve for, so you might have to do weights manually.

Comment: P.S. If I'm correct in understanding you saying, "I'm yet to figure this out," to mean that you're not yet familiar with manual weighting, here is a good YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyelx0TsmSpcgsINPt6fOh3yWjTjk2Nz9

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I was afraid I'd have to manually weight it.

Comment: Hold on, I think I need to clarify. That's exactly what I'm saying--you might have to manually weight it. I gave you the tutorial in case you DID end up having to manually weight it. However, don't fear yet--as I said, I'm not very experienced with rigging/animation, so somebody with more knowledge might come along and give you a better solution. But if you do have to weight manually, it's not nearly as bad as you might think.

Comment: Thanks yeah that's why I left this open, just incase someone does have a solution to this because it will help me in the future, I want to continue working with comples models, and want to find the most efficient workflow I can. But for the time being I've begun weight painting this one by hand, Thank you for the tutorial, I am a bit familiar with the process its just my my sloppy topology making life difficult, but lesson learned.

Comment: OK, cool. I just wanted to make sure, as I did not want to instill you with false hope.